# Unable to connect with bitcore testnet getting following error 525 Origin SSL Handshake Error

Tags: javascript, blockchain, bitcore

I'm trying to create a transcation on the the bitcoin test network. When I run insight.getUnspentUtxos() it return an error.

```
var bitcore = require('bitcore-lib');

var explorers = require('bitcore-explorers');
var insight = new explorers.Insight('testnet');

var value = Buffer.from('I am trying to create new private key');
var hash = bitcore.crypto.Hash.sha256(value);
var BN = bitcore.crypto.BN.fromBuffer(hash);
var privateKeyNew = bitcore.PrivateKey(BN, 'testnet')
var myAddress = privateKeyNew.toAddress()
console.log(myAddress);

var newValue = Buffer.from('I am trying to create new private key but that can be risky');
var newhash = bitcore.crypto.Hash.sha256(newValue);
var newBN = bitcore.crypto.BN.fromBuffer(newhash);
var privateKey = bitcore.PrivateKey(newBN, 'testnet')
var address = privateKey.toAddress();
console.log(address);

insight.getUnspentUtxos(myAddress, ( err, utxo ) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    } else {
        let tx = bitcore.Transaction()
        tx.from(utxo);
        tx.to(address,10000);
        tx.fee(50000);
        tx.change(myAddress);
        tx.sign(privateKeyNew);
        tx.serialize();

        insight.broadcast(tx.toString(), (error, txid) => {
            if(error) {
                return error;
            } else { 
                console.log(txid);
        }
    })
}
```

})

As the UnspentUtxos() execute it give some long massive error. Which describe error 525 Origin SSL Hanshake Error

Answer (score -1):

`bitcore` is using `bitpay` as the default provider server, and for some reason, it is not working. They also recommend changing the default server in the [docs](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-explorers/blob/master/docs/index.md).
Try changing the provider to `zelcore` like this:

```
const explorers = require("bitcore-explorers");
const insight = new explorers.Insight("https://explorer.btc.zelcore.io");
```

More explanation [here](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-explorers/issues/48)